# Database Error - DigitalOcean + Strapi & Postgress

Tags: deployment, strapi

I am trying to push my local strapi instance to my DigitalOcean application. I have setup the correct .env variables inside my DigitalOcean app and before it worked with a local sqllite database. However now I am trying to make it work with Postgress and the DB from DigitalOcean. It looks like it is trying to create the table twice for some reason. Inside my strapi config folder I have the /env/production/database.js file setup correctly as following:

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  connection: {
    client: "postgres",
    connection: {
      host: env("DATABASE_HOST", "127.0.0.1"),
      port: env.int("DATABASE_PORT", 5432),
      database: env("DATABASE_NAME", "strapi"),
      user: env("DATABASE_USERNAME", "strapi"),
      password: env("DATABASE_PASSWORD", "strapi"),
      schema: env("DATABASE_SCHEMA", "public"), // Not required
      ssl: {
        ca: env("DATABASE_CA"), // For self-signed certificates
      },
    },
    debug: false,
  },
});
```

The error I am getting in my console is the following:

```
[2024-01-07 06:49:34] yarn run v1.22.21
[2024-01-07 06:49:34] $ strapi start
[2024-01-07 06:49:44] [2024-01-07 06:49:44.344] debug: ⛔️ Server wasn't able to start properly.
[2024-01-07 06:49:44] [2024-01-07 06:49:44.346] error: create table "public"."components_contact_information_section_contact_information_sections_components" ("id" serial primary key, "entity_id" integer null, "component_id" integer null, "component_type" varchar(255) null, "field" varchar(255) null, "order" double precision null) - relation "components_contact_information_section_contact_information_sect" already exists
[2024-01-07 06:49:44] error: create table "public"."components_contact_information_section_contact_information_sections_components" ("id" serial primary key, "entity_id" integer null, "component_id" integer null, "component_type" varchar(255) null, "field" varchar(255) null, "order" double precision null) - relation "components_contact_information_section_contact_information_sect" already exists
[2024-01-07 06:49:44]     at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/workspace/backend/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287:98)
[2024-01-07 06:49:44]     at Parser.handlePacket (/workspace/backend/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
[2024-01-07 06:49:44]     at Parser.parse (/workspace/backend/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
[2024-01-07 06:49:44]     at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/workspace/backend/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
[2024-01-07 06:49:44]     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:517:28)
[2024-01-07 06:49:44]     at TLSSocket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
[2024-01-07 06:49:44]     at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:368:12)
[2024-01-07 06:49:44]     at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:341:9)
[2024-01-07 06:49:44]     at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:278:10)
[2024-01-07 06:49:44]     at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)
[2024-01-07 06:49:44] error Command failed with exit code 1.
[2024-01-07 06:49:44] info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
[]
```

What options do I have left in this case to make it work with the PG database?